# Binding Listview to multiple Object datasources ASP.net 3.5

Tags: listview, binding, object, hierarchical-data

I am using Object as the data source to my Listview and trying to display data in a Hierarchical manner.  I am not able to figure out how to bind these objects to my listviews. Below pasted is the code. 
I am trying to place Listview inside another listview, inside another listview inorder to display data in a hierarchical manner.  Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance
M.

```
 
public class AutoElements 
    {
       public class results_dataset
        {
            public List claimsHistory { get; set; }
            public int count {get; set;}
        }
       public class Claims_history
        {
            public List claim { get; set; }
        }
        public class Claim : ClaimType
        {
            public string first_payment_date { get; set; }

        }
     }
```

Code to extract data from XML :

```
 

 public class ClaimsProcessing
    {
      public AutoElements.results_dataset GetResultDataset()
         {
             AutoElements.results_dataset  resultdatasets =
             (from b in query.Descendants(xmlns + "results_dataset")
                  select new AutoElements.results_dataset
                     {
                       claimsHistory = (from c in query.Descendants(xmlns + "claims_history")
                                       select new 
                                       AutoElements.Claims_history
                                        {
                                          claim = (from d in query.Descendants(xmlns + "claim")
                                                  select new AutoElements.Claim()
                                                  {
                                                first_payment_date = d.Element(xmlns+"fpdate").Value
                                                  }
                                         }
                      }.ToList(),
                       count = (int) (int)c.Elements(xmlns + "claim").Count()
```

```
        }
  }
```

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ClueAutoElements" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetResultDataset" 
   TypeName="CLUEAuto.BusinessLogic.ClaimsProcessing"></asp:ObjectDataSource>  
              <asp:ListView ID="lv" runat="server" DataSourceID="ClueAutoElements" OnSorting="LvSorting" OnSorted="LvSorted">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <tr id="row" runat="server" class="group">
         <th class="first" runat="server">
          <img src="_assets/img/plus.png" alt='Group: <%# Eval("claimsHistory") %>' /> 
         </th>
         <th colspan="5" runat="server">(<%# Eval("count") %> )</th>
       </tr>
    ?????   <asp:ListView ID="lvItems" runat="server" DataSourceID='<%# Eval("?????") %>'>
    ?????   </asp:ListView>
    </ItemTemplate></asp:ListView>
```